# Crystal Reports: Get value (INT) based of two db comparison

Tags: arrays, database, crystal-reports, report

New here and new to Crystal Reports.
  Here is my problem:

I need to get a number value when looking into two databases. One holds strings and the other numbers. This needs to be from the last 7 days. What more is, I then need to compare that number, with the number that is expected for the next 63 days and only print those that are smaller. Any help is greatly appriciated!

Comment: Can you add some sample data

Comment: Sorry for the extremely long respons time. Figured it out by myself, but thanks for asking! :)